# Find optimale constant in Poincaré's inequality and Gagliardo-Niremberg inequality.

Tags: real-analysis, sobolev-spaces, euler-lagrange-equation

I would like to find a way to find the most optimale constant Poincaré's inequality in a first time and Gagliardo-Niremberg inequality in a second time but in very simple case, i.e. in dimension $1$, for radial functions, and maybe in the first time for $u\in W^{1,1}(\mathbb R)$ (or in fact $\mathcal C^1(\mathbb R)$ if it's easier). I found many articles on the internet as

1) [Best constants for Gagliardo–Nirenberg inequalities and applications to nonlinear diffusions](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0021782402012667)

2) [BEST CONSTANT IN A THREE-PARAMETER POINCARE´
INEQUALITY](https://link.springer.com/content/pdf/10.1007%2Fs10958-011-0583-4.pdf)

3) https://hal.archives-ouvertes.fr/hal-01318727/document

4) [Best Constant in Sobolev Inequality](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.615.4193&rep=rep1&type=pdf)

But it's for the moment much to complicate for me. I really want to find easy cases for the moment before to go in generalization.

Comment: You could state the inequality you're interested in. Is it on $\mathbb R$ or $(0,1)$, for $W_0^{1,1}$ or functions with zero average, what norm ($L^1$ or $L^{1^*}$) would you like to estimate? Also, do you know any standard proof and does it yield the optimal constant?

Comment: @MichałMiśkiewicz: On $\mathbb R$ (the aim would be to find the optimal constant for Carrafelli-Kohn-Niremberg inequality over $\mathbb R^d$ for some class of function, it's almost Gagliardo-Niremberg inequality but in fractional spaces)

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't recognize these theorems under these names. That's why I asked for a statement.

Comment: @MichałMiśkiewicz: I see, thank you for your interest. The motivation is to find the optimal constant for $$\|u\|_{L^r(\mathbb R^d)}\leq C[u]_{W^{s,p}(\mathbb R^d)}\|u\|_{L^q(\mathbb R^d)},$$ where $$\frac{1}{r}+\frac{\gamma }{d}=a\left(\frac{1}{p}+\frac{\alpha -s}{d}\right)+(1-a)\left(\frac{1}{q}+\frac{\beta }{d}\right),$$ $p>1,q\geq 1, a\in(0,1],s\in (0,1),\alpha ,\beta ,\gamma \in \mathbb R$. But before, I would like just to stud the case $\|u\|_{L^p}\leq C\|\nabla u\|_{L^p}$, then $\|u\|_{L^r}\leq C\|\nabla u\|_{L^p}$

Comment: and then, $\|u\|_{L^r}\leq C\|u\|^a_{L^p}\|u\|_{L^q}^{1-a}$ for good function (as radiale), before attacking the general case. Let me know it's unclear.